# Is there any way of running flutter headlessly to generate videos?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been trying to generate videos from widgets from flutter. I am not able to find a way to do `flutter run` without a device.

I am currently using `flutter test` to run a web server to which takes screenshots of the widget. This works but it consumes a lot of memory. Is there any other way of running flutter without a device or ui ?

Comment: use simulator from android studio

Comment: No i cannot use emulators. I just want to create a tool which records a video of flutter widget. I want to run this as a web server

Comment: you want to rec through web version right ?